# BlockingDeque does not unblock after item is inserted in queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am at a loss. I have a BlockingDeque

```
private class Consumer extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (connection.isReady()) {
                    final Item item = queue.takeFirst();
                    try {
                        ListenableFuture<Result> listenableFuture = connection.submitItem(item);
                        Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, new FutureCallBackImpl<Result>(item));
                    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                        LOGGER.debug("Slow down submission of tasks we have a queue full in connection");
                        queue.addFirst(item);

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("Interrupted. I will not propagate up because I own this thread");

        }
    }
}
```

This code normally blocks at `queue.takeFirst()` when no items are in the queue. However, it does not unblock once I add the item as expected. While debugging I can see the items being in the `queue` and also when I stop Tomcat I serialize the `queue`. Upon starting it I de-serialize the queue and at that point the `queue.takeFirst()` retrieves the item (the same that previously did not retrieve) and submits it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

***EDIT***

To stress my point a bit more. If I change the `queue.takeFirst()` with a `queue.pollFirst()` and adjust the code slightly to ignore passes that yield `null` `items` then the code works as expected.

Comment: I can imagine that (i) you are not adding to the queue or (ii) you are not taking from the same queue or (iii) you are actually taking from the queue but think you are not or (iv) the code that takes is never executed...

Comment: As I said in my edit if I change the code to pollFirst then it works. I am sure that (i), (ii) do not apply. For (iii) the debugger should stop at the breakpoint I put inside the try. Again for (iv) the code is executed if I stop and start the code with the serialization/deserialization I explained

Comment: Without a piece of code that reproduces your problem we can only make guesses... You should try and create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `pollFirst` is the wrong way to do it in practice.  You aren't blocking anymore and would spin indefinitely unless you end the thread with a null response.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your code don't enter the `if` because `connection.isReady()` returns `false`.

Check it to be sure that it really stops waiting for the first item in the queue.

Comment: While debugging I see that the thread blocks in queue.takeFirst(). Also why pollFirst() works correctly in this case?

Comment: While you are blocked on the takeFirst in the debugging check the size of the queue

Comment: I have and the size increases as I submit items. I can even see the items in the queue and I see them serialized when I stop tomcat. Also once I start again tomcat and deserialize the queue they are actually sent via the same code.

Answer (score 0):

So Let me explain why this piece of code will not work when items are added to the queue next time (i.e. after it dequeued all the elements first)

When the queue becomes empty for the first time, the call to this code `final Item item = queue.takeFirst();` will throw InterruptedException, which is getting caught by code outside while loop, so the code will never return to the while loop again. Putting first try block inside while loop will resolve the first issue.

Secondly, it needed to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupted()` inside catch block to pass the while condition next time so that it is ready to read for future element addition into queue. Infact I didn't understand the reason for calling this line of code `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`.

Currently I am writing interesting blog for BlockingDeque (WIP), soon you will find more information at my blog http://singletonjava.blogspot.com

Comment: The reason why pollFirst() will work because it never throws any InterruptedException and code never goes out of while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input. By the time the interrupted exception is thrown I truly intend leaving the while loop. Also I did not set `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` on purpose inside the catch. I have found the error and I will update the answer so as to explain it but I am going to do this in a bit as I need to come up with a solution as well

Comment: Perhaps, you should try to explain in more details what you intended to achieve with this piece of code, which will help others to be more in-line to your thinking rather than assumption.